Exhaustive switch in C#
I would like to switch to exhaustive switch in C# in .NET 8 so it will work similar way like some modern programing languages (Rust, ..), but I cannot make it work.
I try to replicate the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68227845/518530
#pragma warning restore CS8509
#pragma warning disable CS8524

string SeverityToString(Severity severity)
{
    switch (severity)
    {
        case Severity.Error:
            return "Error";
        case Severity.Warning:
            return "Warning";
        //default: // default should be automatically generated by pragmas above, isnt it?
        //    throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(severity.ToString(), (int)severity, severity.GetType());
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(SeverityToString(Severity.Error));

public enum Severity
{
    Warning,
    Error,
}

But anyway I still get compilation error, for some reason, the compiler automatically does not generate the default statement if it should
  Program.cs(5, 8): [CS0161] 'SeverityToString(Severity)': not all code paths return a value

Why it does not work? Why the default statement is not generated by compiler?

I may be wrong but as far as I'm aware disabling a warning doesn't automatically make the code valid. The compiler won't guess what you want to do for the default case.

A compilation error is different to a warning. You can choose to disable warnings but errors are still errors.

You cannot just ignore a compiler error. If you have an error, your code will not compile and you have to fix this error. This is different with warnings. You can ignore a warning (but whether this is wise is a different question. I don't recommend that).
In your case, you can turn your error into a warning when you use a switch expression. You have a switch statement. Reformulate your code to a switch expression:
string SeverityToString(Severity severity)
{
    return severity switch
    {
        Severity.Error => "Error",
        Severity.Warning => "Warning",
        _ => throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(severity.ToString(), (int)severity, severity.GetType())
    };
}

If you remove the last last line, you will get a compiler warning instead of an error. If you enter an invalid input a SwitchExpressionException with the message "Non-exhaustive switch expression failed to match its input" will be thrown.
Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPN79q

I'm sure you agree though, that moving something from a compile-time error to a run-time error is an absolutely awful idea.

The provided answers finally got me to this working solution
Add .editorconfig to Solution Items
with content:
root = true
[*.cs]
# exhaustive csharp pattern matching
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8524.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8509.severity = error

Modify the code to the following:
string SeverityToString(Severity severity)
{
    return severity switch
    {
        Severity.Error => "Error",
        Severity.Warning => "Warning",
    };
}

Console.WriteLine(SeverityToString(Severity.Error));

public enum Severity
{
    Warning,
    Error,
}

So this way, the discard operator (default case) is generated automatically, you do not need to write it by yourself. And if you add new enum, you will see compilation error, that the new enum value needs to be handled in the pattern matching. It works really nice.
